# AWS RDS General SSD or Provisioned IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently I have a RDS m4.2xlarge MySQL DB with 200GB of disk space allotted using general SSD, which gives me a limit of about 600 IOPS.

Looking at the monitoring I can see the most of the time the write IOPS are right at the 600 IOPS limit and can't go higher, then there are some short periods a lull followed by a burst over the 600 (I assume while my credits earned during the lull are burned).  After the credits are used up it's back to the 600 limit.

My question is: is there are downside to running at the limit 99% of the time?  My write queue depth is normally less than 2 and never really gets above 3.

Would I see any benefit buying provisioned IOPS (of say 1500) to handle the maximum peak requirements?

Currently I'm not really having any problems with the database, other than an occasional deadlock, but this seems to be expected for the amount of transactions going through the DB.

[image: Example of 24hr monitor]

Comment: Normally General IOPS is enough for transnational application unless there is very special types of queries which are IOPS intensive which happens most of the time.

Comment: The storage shows "Free Storage Space" (so I'm only using about 9GB out of the 200GB)

Comment: I read it wrong, so corrected the above comment. Did you check whether it is due to read or write? and it seems there is a sudden spike on read also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS documentation

> Baseline I/O performance for General Purpose SSD storage is 3 IOPS for each GiB, with a minimum of 100 IOPS. This relationship means that larger volumes have better performance. For example, baseline performance for a 100-GiB volume is 300 IOPS. Baseline performance for a 1-TiB volume is 3,000 IOPS. And baseline performance for a 5.34-TiB volume is 16,000 IOPS.

In most cases the cheaper alternative is simply increase the disk space and get more IOPS allocated